# Can I create 2 versions of timer job from 1 solution and deploy them to Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

I have created a timer job and deployed to Sharepoint 2013 called "Timerjob Employee"

is it possible to modify my existing solution so I can create another timer job called "Timerjob Manager" (with minor differences to the original solution) and deploy to Sharepoint 2013 so I can see both jobs listed in Job Defitions in Central Administration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes,** it should work! but it will require to add **another feature** to the second timer job `"Timerjob Manager"` class.

---

**In your case,** I think if you have a minor change, so I prefers

To bundle the two timer job in only one, and manage the code logic using **IF** condition as the following:

```
If(Type= "Manager")
{
    DoSomething(true);
}
else
{
   DoSomething(false);
}
void DoSomething(bool flag)
 {
   // your code
 }
```

Or isolate it to another solution, or manage it in one solution as I above mentioned. it's up to you :)

Comment: thanks Mohamed. yes I ended up adding another feature.

Answer (score 0):

Each timer job maps to a unique class, create another class inherit from [SPJobDefinition](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sharepoint-server) with unique Title just like you did as existing timer job(Copy&paste and modify the proper coding part, class name, job title, timer job schedule).

[You should know this, while may helpful for your reference.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/b8e86c/how-to-create-timer-job-in-sharepoint-2013/)